# Best way to use vue.js 3 for multiple root element interactivity and with multiple pages

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I know how to build a SPA with Typescript Vue.js 3 and Vite or Vue-Cli.

But now I have to add interactivity on different div element from multiples pages generated with PHP script.

What is the best way to do it ( with typescript ).

Example, a page generated from PHP like this :

- header ← vue.js interactivity to menu
- cart page ← vue.js interactivity on cart form and products
- footer ← vue.js interactivity on newsletter form

Another page generated from php like this

- header ← vue.js interactivity to menu
- product page ← vue.js interactivity on basket + product
- footer ← vue.js interactivity on newsletter form

I don’t see how to build it because of multiple div root elements ( menu, basket, forms... ) and code generated from PHP.
Then some pages need some vue.js code that other pages doesn't need.

Any help or sample will be useful !

Thanks a lot.

Best regards

Comment: I hope I understood you right. Then I would think of using vuex. Your call to the PHP backend are the actions, then store the received HTML as "state". You inject this "state" at the appropriate parts of your vuejs app.